# MySQL CASE with LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-like

I'm having an issue with my MySQL Query, I'm using the case to give it a sort order. The order depends on the serial number.

My query is:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT id, price, itemnr, itemnr_ori, link, name, setinfo 
CASE WHEN itemnr_ori LIKE '%-%-s%' THEN 0 WHEN itemnr_ori LIKE 'z-%-%' THEN 1
 WHEN itemnr_ori LIKE 'ak-%' THEN 2
 WHEN itemnr_ori LIKE 'fdc-%' THEN 3
 WHEN itemnr_ori LIKE 'max-%' THEN 4
 ELSE 5 END
 AS sort_order FROM items2 WHERE category1 = 'Overige' AND category2 = 'Afrikaanse Overige' ORDER BY sort_order ASC, price ASC, itemnr_ori ASC
```

I'm getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN itemnr_ori LIKE '%-%-s%' THEN 0 WHEN itemnr_ori LIKE 'z-%-%' THEN 1 WH' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're going to be spending any time with MySQL get used to reading the error messages carefully - they usually tell you EXACTLY where the error is in your code. In this case, the first error is at the word CASE and so you can see that you missed the comma. Learn to love the error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a comma, like this

```
setinfo,
CASE WHEN .. END
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed my really stupid error... :)